# Maven profile for single module

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

I have a multi module maven project, which builds successfully, I'd like to build **just one** of the modules I have. How would I do that with [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) ? I could do it from console in two ways, one way is go to the child module and `mvn package` or I could use reactor to build just one module.

Can I do the same thing with profiles? By modifying POM? Thank you

**EDIT**

If is impossible from POM, can I do it from settings.xml ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To implement this with profiles, you could use two profiles, one `<activeByDefault>` with all modules and another one with the wanted module only. Something like this:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>all</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <modules>
      <module>module-1</module>
      ...
      <module>module-n</module>
    </modules>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>module-2</id>
    <modules>
      <module>module-2</module>
    </modules>
  </profile>
<profiles>
```

And then call it like this:

```
mvn -Pmodule-2 package
```

Two things to note here:

1. You need to move the `<modules>` from the POM in a "default" profile (because `<modules>` from a profile are only additive, they do not hide the modules declared in the POM).
2. By marking it as `<activeByDefault>`, the "default" profile will be picked if nothing else is active but deactivated if something else is.

One could even parametrize the name of the module and pass it as property:

```
<profiles>
  ...
  <profile>
    <id>module-x</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>module-name</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <modules>
      <module>${module-name}</module>
    </modules>
  </profile>
<profiles>
```

And invoke maven like this:

```
mvn -Dmodule-name=module-2 package
```

But this is a poor implementation IMHO, I prefer the `-pl` "advanced" reactor options (less xml, much more power and flexibility):

```
mvn -pl module-2 package
```

Comment: @Pascal Thivent Just brilliant .. I don't know what to say .. thank you m8, you are second to none when it comes to maven

Comment: I agree @Pascal is a maven genius. I would also add the voice that it is cleaner to use a reactor build than configuring multiple profiles.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome additivity nature of maven default `<modules>` working with `<profiles>`, you can use reactor with particular profile, e.g.:

```
mvn -pl module-2 -Pprofile-name package
```

This will package module-2 defined in profile-name and not in default profile.