Maven multimodules and profiles
I can not understand how to manage modules and profiles. Could someone explain me?
For example in parent pom i added 5 modules, because I have structure like that
parent
    db
    common
    core
    security
    web

I want to start test only in core module, which depends on another except web. I want do it with some profile.
I think it looks like in parent.pom
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    <profile>
        <id>core-no-test</id>
        <build><plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
             </configuration>
       </plugin>
       </plugins></build>
    </profile>
... another profiles
</profiles>

And here also for db I want to create integration-test which shouldn`t start with the whole project but only with specific profile.
And a lot of other ideas and tasks I have but how it should be resolved?
It is something like in parent pom
<profile>
...
<modules><module>db</module></modules>
<build><plugins>...</plugins></build>

Ant put logic in each profile in the parent pom or should I divide every specific builds in each child pom? And how to start that?

Modules based on a profile etc. is a bad idea... running unit and or integration tests can be done simpler... https://github.com/khmarbaise/youtube-videos/blob/main/episode-2/pom.xml Why do you like to start the tests on command only in a single module? Why not using your IDE for that?

Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

You can do this without modifying your POMs with the following commandline options:
mvn -pl core -am -Pprofile1,profile2 test

See the full reference of CLI options at https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.9.9/maven-embedder/cli.html
You can specify the profiles either in the top level POM when they are valid for all the modules, or in the individual modules. Expect warnings for each module where a specific profile is not available that you specified (especially due to the -am option that will build more than just the specified module).

I saw that a lot of times, but I need to build specific profiles as I mentioned: integration-test/unit-test/ test-covers/other specific builds. That answer close to my question but a little bit differ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400984/maven-profile-for-single-module

@Dred I updated the answer with a bit of information about the profiles.

In that case, Why should I use -pl options if I choose Profile in the command?  And also, If profile1 defined in child (core) module I can still call mvn -pl core -am -Pprofile1 test from the parent directory?

Because it will be much harder to establish and maintain the profiles, as you will have to disable the tests in all the modules that you do not want to start with a profile. (So you have to implement a profile for disabling tests, instead of straightforward commanding what you want to do). And this will not prevent build, you will have to additionally disable that - and when you introduce a new plugin that links into the build cycle, you will have to disable that again, etc.

Ok, thank you for your answer but it wasn`t answer for my question. You gave a good advise but not an answer
